# Java - convert object to map for use in JSON

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have an object, let's just call it

```
class Foo {
    String greeting = "Hello";
    int age = 21;
}
```

That I want to be converted to a map like `"greeting" => "Hello", "age" => 21` This will be used as an argument in `JSONSerializer.toJSON(arg)`

Languages like Perl and Python are very good at this sort of interchange.  What's a good practice way to do this in Java?

Comment: This can be achieved using reflection http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make this conversion prior to the serialization.

Gson would use your object directly and make it a JSON map.

Use this for example :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
writer.write(gson.toJson(foo)); // foo is an instance of Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) directly to serialise POJOs. Works really well out of the box.

```
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

Foo foo = new MyFoo("hello", 21);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Writer writer= new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, foo);
String json = writer.toString();
System.out.println(json);
```